# how to submit a form onChange with JqueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a select menu that iam using to change the laguage to this site.

Onchange iam trying to refresh the current page and pass the variables to the link or the adress.

this is the code ;

```
 <form action='index.php' method="get" id='myForm'>
<select name="language" id="language" data-theme="b" style="float:right;" data-native-menu="false" 
onchange="$.mobile.changePage( 'index.php', {
type: 'get', 
data: $('form#myForm').serialize()} );">

                <option value="eng">English</option>
                <option value="ita">Italian</option>
                <option value="esp">Spanish</option>
                <option value="fr">French</option>
            </select>
</form>
```

However as a result i get somethingh along the lines of ; **index.php?language=ita&language=eng&language=eng&language=eng&language=eng**

iam trying to get only **index.php?language=ita**

Also would it be possible to point the submit to the current page and not index.php

Thanks in adavanced to any one with the time to help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gregor,

Try to use unobtrusive javascript instead of inline. something along the following lines may work:

```
<form action='index.php' method="get" id='myForm'>
    <select name="language" id="language" data-theme="b" style="float:right;" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="eng">English</option>
        <option value="ita">Italian</option>
        <option value="esp">Spanish</option>
        <option value="fr">French</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#language').change(function() {
            $.mobile.changePage('index.php', {
                type: 'get',
                data: $('form#myForm').serialize()
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

untested, so no guarantees, but at least a little cleaner. Also, if you flesh out the requirement here (i presume to change page based on the select option values), I think we could find a solution pretty swiftly.

Comment: i have a php script that based on the value that is passed it changes the language , the select menue from this example is intended only to refresh the page , prefferebly not index.php but the current page and pass it the value from the select, if i have not been clear plz ask me to clrify

Comment: gregor - ok, that helps a little more. let me have a ponder and get back at some point later then..